# Locking another computer using sockets without interrupting the connection

Tags: python, sockets, networking, operating-system

I am trying to set up a server that can send each client - commands.
One command is 'lock' which locks the screen of the client.
When a client gets the word "lock" it runs this code on the client:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

This code does lock the screen however- it ends my connection with the client..
How can I make the client stay connected but still locked?

Note: The locking is not forever! it is only once, like putting the client's computer in sleep mode until he wants to unlock the screen.

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks for helping!

Server:

```
import socket

def main():

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 4582))
    print("Waiting for connections...")
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print ("New connection from: ", addr)

    while 1:
        command = input("Enter command> ")


        if command == 'shutdown':
            sock.send(b'shutdown')
        elif command == 'lock':
            sock.send(b'lock')
        else:
            print ("Unknown command")

        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print (data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import ctypes


def main():

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4582))


    while 1:

        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print (data)

        if data == 'lock':
            sock.send(b'locking')
            ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()

        sock.recv(1024)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy it's actually my only code, only sending the word "lock" to the client and running this line (ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation() )
But still after I run this, it does lock the client but then the connection cuts

Comment: @Jayjayyy I put the whole socket communication in a while loop.. 
I need to try it again, you may be currect!

Comment: @Jayjayyy Hey, I updated my code, still when I send "lock" the connection cuts...  (ignore the shutting down function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the example from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html#example) to your needs.

Example for `server.py`:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4582

with socket.socket() as s:
    print('Waiting for connection...')
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = input('Which command? ')
            if data in ['lock', 'shutdown']:
                conn.send(data.encode())
            else:
                print('Command unknown')
```

Example for `client.py`:

```
import ctypes
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4582

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            print('Server disconnected')
            break
        print('Received command:', data)
        if data == 'shutdown':
            print('Shutting down client...')
            break
        if data == 'lock':
            print('Locking...')
            ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

Comment: Thanks! it works just fine (However I had to switch to py 2.7 and change some things with the "with socket.socket() as s: " but it does work, and the connection stays strong! Thank you!